Spring boot microservice and AWS Redshift
I'm trying to build a microservice that needs to extract data from AWS Redshift and insert that data to AS400 db.
Is it possible to have both DB's configured in the application-yaml and how can I achieve this?
appplication-dev.yaml
spring:
  mvc:
    format:
      date: yyyy-MM-dd
      date-time: yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:redshift://redshift.amazonaws.com:5439/dwsa
    username: root
    password: root
    driver-class-name: com.amazon.redshift.jdbc42.Driver
  jpa:
    database-platform: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
    show-sql: true

Service.java:
    @Transactional
    @Override
    public void transferData() {
        List<WkDerecognizedLoanRecommended> redshiftData = derecognitionRepository.findAll();

        for (WkDerecognizedLoanRecommended redshiftRecord : redshiftData) {
            DERECOGNITIONSTAGING as400Record = new DERECOGNITIONSTAGING();
            as400Record.setArrearsBal(redshiftRecord.getArrearsBal());
            as400Record.setDerecognizedDate(redshiftRecord.getDerecognizedDate());
            as400Record.setArrearsPercentage(redshiftRecord.getArrearsPercentage());
            as400Record.setLoanReference(redshiftRecord.getLoanReference());
            as400Record.setFirstDefaultDate(redshiftRecord.getFirstDefaultDate());
            as400Record.setLastReceiptAmount(redshiftRecord.getLastReceiptAmount());
            as400Record.setLastReceiptDate(redshiftRecord.getLastReceiptDate());
            as400Record.setOutstandingBal(redshiftRecord.getOutstandingBal());
            as400Record.setMonthsSinceLastPayment(redshiftRecord.getMonthsSinceLastPayment());
            as400Record.setMonthsSinceFirstDefault(redshiftRecord.getMonthsSinceFirstDefault());
            as400Record.setCreateDate(LocalDate.now());

            derecognitionStaggingRepository.save(as400Record);
        }
    }

